# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException - notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, wait, notify

I'm trying to `notify()` a particular thread from another thread run method. I'm facing `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` Both the threads are started in a main class.

Note:
    All three are different classes.

MAIN CLASS

```
public class queueCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BlockingQueue<testObjectClass> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<testObjectClass>();
    Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

    Thread produceThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                producer.produce();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                consumer.consume();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    producer.setConsumerThread(consumerThread);
    consumer.setProducerThread(produceThread);

    produceThread.start();
    consumerThread.start();

}
```

}

PRODUCER CLASS

```
class Producer {
BlockingQueue<testObjectClass> queue;
testObjectClass objectSample = new testObjectClass("TEST", "TEST");
Thread consumerThread;


public void setConsumerThread(Thread t1) {
    this.consumerThread = t1;
}

public Producer(BlockingQueue<testObjectClass> outQueue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.queue = outQueue;
}

public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            // Producer thread waits while list is full
            try {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    // Notifies the consumer thread that now it can start consuming
                    this.wait();
                }
                i = i + 1;
                objectSample.setValues("String ", String.valueOf(i));
                queue.put(objectSample);
                System.out.println("Adding element: " + objectSample.stringMessage());
                consumerThread.notify();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

CONSUMER CLASS

```
 class Consumer {
BlockingQueue<testObjectClass> queue;
testObjectClass objectSample;
Thread producerThread;


public void setProducerThread(Thread t1) {
    this.producerThread = t1;
}

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<testObjectClass> outQueue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.queue = outQueue;
}

// Function called by consumer thread
public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            //Consumer thread waits while list is empty.
            while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                this.wait();
            }
            testObjectClass objectX = queue.take();
            System.out.println("\t Taking element: " + objectX.stringMessage());
            producerThread.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

}

HELPER CLASS

```
class testObjectClass {
private String test1;
private String test2;
public testObjectClass(String testString1, String testString2) {
    this.test1 = testString1;
    this.test2 = testString2;
}
public void setValues(String testString1,String testString2) {
    this.test1 = testString1;
    this.test2 = testString2;
}
public String stringMessage() {
    return test1 + test2;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-how-to-solve-illegalmonitorstateexception/

Use this link to get some detail information. Here you are acquiring a lock using one object and releasing the same lock by using a different object.  Use a shared object to acquire a lock and release the lock.